# Рендеринг html из таблиц mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Задача рендерить блоки верстки беря данные из бд (mysql).
[image]

Так выглядит "блок" с именем, описанием и аватаркой. Эта верстка написанная вручную.

```
<div class="container chel"> 
    <div class="row row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-11 people chel">
    <img class="avaimg" src="andreyteyl/123123.gif">
        <div class="name">
        <p>Андрейтейл</p>
        </div>
        <img src="mes.svg" class="sendmes" href="Whais.html">
        <div class="about">
        <p>Эти аватарки...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я же хочу брать информацию из бд и автоматически, в зависимости от количества участников (сколько человек, столько и блоков) отрисовывать их, и заполнять описанием, именем и т.д.
Проблема в том, что я совершенно не понимаю как такое реализовать, с бэком сталкиваюсь впервые. Только тут с горе по полам смог описать проблему, хотя от заголовка можно загнаться в ступор. Сколько не копал тем, нет подходящей.

Comment: А при чем тут бакэнд? При генерации страницы отправляете запрос в БД, получаете оттуда данные, обрамляете их в Вашу верстку, выводите.

Comment: @delikates если речь про пхп, то о чем еще речь может идти, раз не о бекэнде?

Comment: вам тут никто книги о программировании на пхп писать в ответах не будет. Разбейте задачу на части и решайте ее, читая соответствующие разделы руководства по пхп